# Убрать возможность выбора прошедшей даты из datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как убрать возможность выбора прошедшей даты из календаря datetimepicker

Comment: Это какой-то плагин? Можно ссылку на репозиторий?

Comment: Да это плагин выбора даты и времени на jquery http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать текущий день в качестве минимально возможного:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).find('#time').datetimepicker({
  minDate: 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть параметр такой [startDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate), вот с помощью его задаете текущую дату и всё:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    startDate: "17/04/2017"
});
```

Текущую дату можно взять с помощью JavaScript объекта Date:

```
var date = new Date();
var startDate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

Потом подставляете переменную `startDate` в параметр и всё.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    startDate: startDate
});
```

Формат можно указать один из следующих:

> d, dd: Numeric date, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively.
>
> Eg, 5, 05. D, DD: Abbreviated and full weekday names, respectively.
>
> Eg, Mon, Monday. m, mm: Numeric month, no leading zero and leading
> zero, respectively. Eg, 7, 07. M, MM: Abbreviated and full month
> names, respectively. Eg, Jan, January yy, yyyy: 2- and 4-digit years,
> respectively. Eg, 12, 2012.

Comment: К сожалению не вышло